# Papers about backtesting option trading strategies

Tags: options, backtesting, quant-trading-strategies, research, option-strategies

I am looking for all kinds of research concerning option trading strategies. With that I mean papers that publish results on different option trading strategies properly backtested with real-world data.

Comment: "real-world data" as opposed to... "fake data" ;) Interesting question though.

Comment: @JSmaga: Well, not artificially created pseudo-random simulation data but historic real option price data.

Comment: funny how much a bounty can actually wake up people....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did some digging and found the following papers - most of them offering quite a distinct perspective compared to classical option pricing theory!

- [Stock Options as Lotteries by Brian H. Boyer et al. (2011)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1787365)
- [The Efficiency of the Buy-Write Strategy: Evidence from Australia by Tafadzwa Mugwagwa et al. (2010)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1535123)

The following is my favorite: You could do some backtests on your own with freely available data (using the VXO as volatility information) and with any spreadsheet - easy and elegant:

- [How Students Can Backtest Madoff’s Claims by Michael J. Stutzer (2009)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120417044216/http://leeds.colorado.edu/asset/burridge/backtestmadoffsclaims.pdf)
- [Loosening Your Collar: Alternative Implementations of QQQ Collars by Edward Szado et al. (2009)](http://www.isenberg.umass.edu/CISDM/uploads/textWidget/3642.00002/documents/QQQ_Active_Collar_Paper_website_v3.pdf)
- [A Study of Optimal Stock & Options Strategies by Mihir Dash et al. (2008)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1293203)
- [Is There Money to Be Made Investing in Options? A Historical Perspective by James S. Doran et al. (2008)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=873639)

EDIT:
I will update this answer from time to time when new interesting papers arive:

- [15 Years of the Russell 2000 Buy-Write by N. Kapadia and E. Szado (2011)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1928822)

EDIT 2:
I just published a blog post where I replicate the abovementioned paper by Stutzer (2009):

- [Backtesting Options Strategies with R](https://blog.ephorie.de/backtesting-options-strategies-with-r)

In the post, I provide the fully documented R code for your own experiments. For details please consult the post.

Comment: There seems to be a more recent version of the paper "Madoff Mess Motivates" under the title "How students can backtest Madoff's Claims" which reads very nicely.

Edit: heres the link: http://leeds.colorado.edu/asset/burridge/backtestmadoffsclaims.pdf

Answer (score 11):

Since I, too, have been very interested in this question, I will share some of my findings in the dual hope of encouraging comments on the papers and eliciting more activity on this question.

- [Ammann, Skovmand, and Verhofen (2008): Implied and Realized Volatility in the Cross-Section of Equity Options](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1324605)
- [Ang, Bali, and Cakici (2010): The Joint Cross Section of Stocks and Options](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1533089)
- [Bali and Murray (2011): Does Risk-Neutral Skewness Predict the Cross-Section of Equity Option Portfolio](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1572827)
- [Cao and Han (2011): Cross-Section of Option Returns and Stock Volatility](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1786607)
- [Constantinides, Jackwerth, and Savov (2011): The Puzzle of Index Option Returns](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1491469)
- [Deng (2008): Volatility Dispersion Trading](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1156620)
- [Driessen, Lin, and Hemert (2011): How the 52-Week High and Low Affect Option-Implied Volatilities and Stock Return Moments](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1572269)
- [Jones and Shemesh (2010): The Weekend Effect in Equity Option Returns](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1364721)

Answer (score 9):

[Option Traders Use (very) Sophisticated Heuristics, Never the Black–Scholes–Merton Formula](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1012075)

[Stock Price Clustering on Option Expiration Dates](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=519044)

[Option Returns and Volatility Mispricing](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=889947)

Comment: I think only the third one is relevant to the question

Comment: @vonjd: The third one (Goyal and Saretto (2007)) is probably one of the best references in this area, IMO.

Comment: And the first one by the Black Swan himself is like reading hieroglyphics. Wow.